# Creating généric GUI for several subclasses

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm searching a clean pattern to solve the following problem:

I have several type of vehicles (let's say Car, Bike and Truck, all these classes expand the abstract class Vehicle). Each type of vehicle has several specific properties.

I have somewhere a list of vehicle, and i need to build a GUI which makes the user able to select a vehicle, and edit its properties. The result I'd like to achieve is to display a vehicle list (using JList) on the left, and a panel on the right containing the fields needed to edit the selected Vehicle.

I know how to do it when the list contains only one type of items (I use a Jlist on the left, and a custom JPanel on the right). I made one custom panel for each subclass : CarPanel, BikePanel...
My problem is the link between the type of the selected Vehicle and the according panel. Although it would work, I'd like to avoid something like that :

```
if (selectedVehicle instanceof Car) {
    useThisPanel(new CarPanel((Car)selectedVehicle));
} ...
```

because it doesnt seems very maintainable to me.

I also want to avoid something like `useThisPanel(selectedVehicle.getPanel())` because there is no reason any vehicle class should know anything about the way it is displayed

I'm currently working on switching my code to a MVC pattern, but it seems to me it's not enought to solve my problem.

I'm pretty sure I'm not the first one to face this, but I couldn't find any answer or advice to manage this kind of situations.

Comment: Use reflection to get the field names and types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of solving this problem in an OO way is to use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

```
public interface VehicleVisitor<T> {
    T visitCar(Car car);
    T visitTruck(Truck truck);
    T visitBike(Bike bike);
}

public abstract class Vehicle {
    public abstract <T> T accept(VehicleVisitor<T> visitor);
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
    @Override
    public <T> T accept(VehicleVisitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitCar(this);
    }
}

// same for Bike and Truck
```

And finally

```
public class SomeClass {
    private JPanel createPanelFor(Vehicle vehicle) {
        return vehicle.accept(new VehicleVisitor<JPanel>() {
            @Override
            public JPanel visitCar(Car car) {
                return new CarPanel(car);
            }
            // same for Truck and Bike
        }
    }
}
```

This is clean and everything, but it's a bit more difficult to understand than a simple instanceof based solution. It has an advantage though: you can't forget handling a new Vehicle type: it will force you to implement the abstract `accept()` method, which will force you to add another method to the Visitor interface, which will force you to implement it in every visitor.

Comment: Damn, i should have found it myself, this pattern is in my book! It perfectly answers the question. Thank you.